# Enabling Nativescript livesync dev in VS Code Windows

Tags: nativescript

I'm looking at developing in Nativescript w/ Typescript/Ang. under Windows.

Everything runs.

When I try to enable livesync for Android emulator - seems to work if I modify a .ts (typescript) file.

But if I modify a .css file - the watcher seems to detect it and I see a message about "applying changes" - but there's no effect in the emulator. The target program doesn't restart.

How can I get tns watch to work with modifications to css files.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a documented bug in 2.1.0 and the big-fix will be included in 2.2.0 . https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli/issues/1872

Comment: Thanks. What's the update procedure - is it automatic or manual. If the latter - how do I know the current release version and also what's the command to get the latest.

Comment: Manual Upgrade, `npm i nativescript -g` will do it. Best keep an eye out on the GitHub [repo](https://github.com/nativescript/nativescript/milestones), which should have a date for the milestone release.

Comment: You can build your project with the next nativeScript-CLi following the instruction here https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-cli#how-to-build  or you can modify your package.json and instead of version for tns-android and tns-core-modules pass "next" (you will have to clean your platform and node_modules and rebuild)